# How to initialize std::array<std::atomic<bool>> — no copy or move ctors

Tags: c++, stdatomic, stdarray

In my class, I want a `std::array<std::atomic<bool>>`, and I'd like to initialize it via member initialization, in the constructor.

For example:

```
struct Foo {

    Foo()
    : flags{{
        true,
        true
    }}
    { /* no op */ }
    std::array<std::atomic<bool>, 2> flags;
};
```

Sadly, this does not work, giving: `error: use of deleted function 'std::atomic<bool>::atomic(const std::atomic<bool>&)'`

This makes sense, because `std::atomic<bool>` is neither copyable nor movable.

So, somehow, I need to direct-initialize these two flags.

But what's the syntax for it?

Here is a live code link: https://godbolt.org/z/fEsfaWGcn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an initializer-list for each item in the initializer list of the `std::array`. Here is how:

```cpp
struct Foo {
    Foo()
    : flags{{
        {true},
        {true}
    }}
    { /* no op */ }
    std::array<std::atomic<bool>, 2> flags;
};
```

While the syntax is a bit strange, it works well (tested on GCC, Clang, MSVC and ICC).

Comment: My goodness, thank you. I should have known the solution to all things initializer-list is "add more curly braces" (:

Comment: I don't suppose there's a scalable way to write this which doesn't require you to repeat yourself N times for an array of N bools?

Comment: @PeterCordes: I suspect not easily, since it's the same with a raw array (eg: `bool a[100] = { true, true, ... }`), which std::array thinly wraps. However, I wouldn't be surprised if there's some crazy template metaprogramming solution that I don't want to think about...

Comment: It's also interesting here that including the type name before the curlies explicitly does *not* work, in this case. That is, it must be written exactly `{true}` and not `std::atomic<bool>{true}`. Confused me a bit.

Comment: @jwd: Your 2nd comment makes sense to me: `{true}` is initializing the array element or named variable from an initializer-list with a `bool` in it.  `std::atomic<bool>{true}` constructs an anonymous `atomic<bool>` and then tries to copy-construct from that, which obviously won't work.

Comment: @PeterCordes: yeah, I suppose that's the truth, but I had gotten used to writing `Foo{...}` when constructing a `Foo` object, and typically the copy is elided, so I have more readable code at no extra runtime cost. But in this case, I specifically *cannot* include the type alongside the curlies, which to me is worse for readability — I have to go check the declaration to know what exactly is being constructed. But for a non-movable, non-copyable type like `std::atomic<...>` it's simply the only option available, it seems.

Comment: @PeterCordes If there is N bools, then you can use some fancy templates generating initializer-list for you. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/ozMaP811o) is a demo code. I personally think the code should be redesigned in such case (in order to avoid future headaches). Note that, since C++20, `std::atomic_ref` solves this problem elegantly (since `std::atomic_ref` is copy-constructible).

Comment: @JérômeRichard: You normally only want to use `atomic_ref` as a temporary, so the right way to use it would be to create an array of plain `bool` and make sure every access to them used an `atomic_ref` constructed on the fly.  If you actually made an array of `atomic_ref<bool>` objects, in asm you'd have an array of pointers, each of which pointed to a bool somewhere.  So you'd need 2 arrays (or much worse, `*(new bool)` for every one, with I think no way get the pointer out of the atomic_ref to ever free it, not to mention overhead of separate allocations.)

Comment: @JérômeRichard: Yeah, a template is probably the way to go.  But note that with the template at global scope, it still only does runtime init of the values, not static init to `1`.  And as a local, if you stop the construction from optimizing away by passing `&f` to another function, it seems to be copying from somewhere instead of just storing `1`s.  At least it does coalesce the stores into one word and one byte, not 5 separate byte copies. https://godbolt.org/z/eoPqsj8js

Comment: @JérômeRichard: Runtime init seems not to be the template's fault: https://godbolt.org/z/n3dWx5978 shows the same asm for initializing explicitly, like your answer.  Initializing only the first 2 gets it to use an immediate `0x00000101` instead of copying, which is silly because AArch64 can construct `0x01010101` in a register in a single instruction. :/  So yeah, the template is just as good as writing it out manually; it's the `std::atomic` and/or `std::array` construction that are causing missed optimizations vs. `bool arr[5] = {true, true, ...};`